# Accessing django app from another app with ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, http

I have a webservice written in django and I want to call it from a non django app with ajax. Both apps run on the same host. When I call the webservice with curl it works fine, but when I call it with ajax from the other app I get a 500 internal server error. There are no errors in the web server log. DEBUG is True, and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']. When I run the dev server and connect to that I get no errors, just the 500 error. I tried setting a breakpoint in the view, but it never makes it there.

I have another django app that I also call and that one works. Both the working and non-working one return JSON data. The working one returns this:

```
render_to_response('hc-config.json', content_type='application/json')
```

And the one that returns the 500 returns this:

```
    response = HttpResponse(jsonOut)
    return response
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening or how I could debug it further?

Comment: Use your **browser** console (and especially the network pane, click on the request which returns a 500) to see what is the result. If debug is True, then you shoud have a Django exception traceback which will help debugging the problem

Comment: I had already done that and there was no traceback. But I found the cause of this issue - I did not have a slash on the end of the URL. I added that, then instead of a 500 I get a 403 Forbidden, which is usually because of no CSRF token, but I am sending that. So I disabled CSRF and then I get a 400 bad request.

Comment: I had same problem and could solve it by correcting the URL and adding CSRF token in urls.py of corresponding app. Whenever you want to send request from one app to another one, you can send it by '../[YOUR APP/Name of Function]'.